# Why a ground loop a problem, not a ground plane(patch attena)?

Tags: ground, emc, grounding, ground-loop, ground-plane

The question is as the title says:

I see various material saying using a solid ground plane. Why would not that be a problem, since a solid ground plane could be a patch antenna?

Answer (score 3):

It is only an antenna if the size of the structure starts to approach about 1/10 th of the wavelength of your frequency of interest.  For example 1 GHz is about 30cm, so ground structures bigger than 3cm start to assist in radiation.  However they are not good radiators unless you are impedance matched to them to transfer maximum power.  So in general a weak EMI signal at 1GHz would not radiate well because they are usually low power and they are not impedance matched to transfer maximum power to the patch of ground.  And the rule of thumb of having more ground almost always beats out any incidental radiation that might leak out.

Comment: Is it correct to say that a ground plane is better than a ground loop because of the impedance matching?

Comment: @richieqianle  A ground loop is typically an unexpected path to the ground plane and then to another area of the circuitry.  This happens when the return path is unintentionally a lower impedance than the nearby ground plane.  They are dependent on a lot of conditions, are non-intuitive and require a fair bit of experience to locate and troubleshoot.